# Qualcomm Atheros AR9565 Wifi Adapter. Can't find drivers

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, lenovo, atheros

I am simply looking for where I can download the drivers(source code is fine, doesn't have to be precompiled) for my wifi adapter. My laptop manufacture is Lenovo and the model is Z50-75. The wifi adapter is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9565. Thank you for reading this and taking the time to help me. Let me know if you need anymore information. Also, I tried looking on Lenovo's website but I couldn't find them there.

**Update 2:** I misread the comments. I updated the question again to put what was asked here.

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no

3: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

**Update 3:** I upgraded to 15.10 for the 4.2 kernel and the adapter didn't work after the upgrade. I was surprised, because I thought that would fix the problem.

---

**Update 4:** I deiced to run Windows 10 on the computer instead. I do enjoy using Linux and the freedoms that come with it(ie; desktop environments, running mostly open source software) but I just changed my mind. **Thank you again everyone for helping me, I feel bad because I feel like I have wasted your time, but if I do happen to change my mind I will have this question to reference to.** If I ever did want to test the latest distros, there are always virtual machines I could use.

Comment: You usually don't need special drivers for Linux. Unless something isn't working, there is no issue here.

Comment: @Zacharee1, I was asking because I can only connect to the Internet via Ethernet. My wifi adapter isn't being shown.

Comment: That should have been your question :p. In Linux, asking for drivers does not imply that the device isn't working.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339724/atheros-qca9565-ar9565-wireless-card-doesnt-work-after-updating

Comment: And this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453033/qualcomm-atheros-qca9565-ar9565-wireless-network-adapter-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: So I would have to install the proper drivers through backports?  Also, when I do ifconfig I don't see my wifi adapter listed. Only ethernet.

Comment: Please edit the question to add results for `lscpi -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all` thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31, The output from that was 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no


1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no


3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: @Jeremy31, Sorry if it is difficult to read.

Comment: @TylerSantos But can YOU read. Please try to read the comments again carefully and do what you were asked.

Comment: Tyler, run `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info` and paste the contents of the wireless-info.txt file at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL it gives you

Comment: @Jeremy31, here is the link. ( http://paste.ubuntu.com/14872204/ )

Comment: You don't have an AR9565 it is a QCA6164

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Comment: @Jeremy31, Oh. Sorry about that. I don't know how I got the QCA6164 mixed up with the AR9565.

Comment: You need to install the backports and firmware from the [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in), the dkms doesn't work in 4.2 kernels