# No WIFI Adapter Found (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) - Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, atheros

I've just started in the "Ubuntu World" and I did the dual boot of the newest version 18.04 aside to my Windows 10.

The installation was successful but apparently I'm not able to connect via wireless. I can't see the "Wifi" icon on the top corner and when I go to Settings --> Wifi, the message "No Wifi adapter found" is displayed.

I've been looking for solutions but wasn't very successful.

Wifi Card: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter.

Thank you,

Leonardo.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/459166/350004

Comment: Apparetly this solution only works for ASUS computer. I’m still having the same problem (my PC is an ACER).